# Genexus Smart Device Offline External Object

Tags: android, objeto, genexus, gradle

Estimados en un modelo GX17 U9 .NET SqlServer Android, estoy intentando integrar una clase java con un external object, he encontrado el siguiente post

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43680,Como+crear+un+External+Object+Offline+para+Android

No me permite importa las clases cuando se debe correr `gradlew publishDebugPublicationToLocalRepository`

Favor si han realizado un caso parecido

Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Esa documentación es de un ejemplo antiguo para Genexus v16. Para un ejemplo actual ver [este sample y seguir su documentación](https://github.com/genexuslabs/SDExtensionsSample)